# Automatically setting the release tag on a GitHub workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to build an action that is triggered on creating a new release on GitHub which works fine, but I would like to reference the tag in my action:

```
name: Build production container

on:
  release:
    types:
      - created

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build the Docker image
        run: |
          echo "${{ SECRET }}" | docker login -u ME --password-stdin docker.pkg.github.com
          docker build app/ -t docker.pkg.github.com/REPO_PATH/image:$VERSION
          docker push docker.pkg.github.com/REPO_PATH/image:$VERSION
        shell: bash
        env:
          VERSION: 0.0.1
```

This is my working action, but I would like to automatically pull the tag into the VERSION environment variable. I read the documentation, especially [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) where the GitHub context is referenced, but I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: Maybe you can use the following [action](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/github-action-get-previous-tag).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I didn't want to use an extra action just to get the tag name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out that the action has a different context for each method documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#push). So the parameter I was looking for is the and I've set my action up after [this example](https://github.community/t/how-to-get-just-the-tag-name/16241/11):

```
name: Build production container

on:
  release:
    types:
      - created

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get Tag Name
        id: tag_name
        run: |
          echo ::set-output name=SOURCE_TAG::${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}

      - name: Build the Docker image
        run: |
          echo "${{ SECRET }}" | docker login -u ME --password-stdin docker.pkg.github.com
          docker build app/ -t docker.pkg.github.com/REPO_PATH/image:$VERSION
          docker push docker.pkg.github.com/REPO_PATH/image:$VERSION
        shell: bash
        env:
          VERSION: ${{ steps.tag_name.outputs.SOURCE_TAG }}
```

This basically adds getting the source parameter as an extra step, this way I can use it in the environment variables of the next step.